# Can a thread exist outside of a process?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

In other words, is it possible to have thread without a process. *I think it's not possible to have thread without a process. A process at least has a main thread.*

Answer (score 6):

Threads run code. So essentially, you are asking whether it is possible to run code without a process.

The answer depends on where you want the code to run.

There are kernel-mode threads that run in the Linux operating system that are not associated with any particular process, and there are [bare-metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bare_machine) embedded systems that have threads, but which have no notion of "process."

If you want a thread running user-mode code in some desktop, server, or mobile OS though, and you don't want it to be associated with any process; then that's probably not going to happen.

Comment: To summarize what you're saying, it's not possible to have a thread outside of a process in user mode, however in kernel mode it's possible.

Comment: @uzluisf, I know that Linux, in particular, uses threads that run in privileged mode, and which are not associated with any process. and I know that Linux kernel developers call those, "kernel threads." Process threads in Linux run in unprivileged (a.k.a., "user") mode when executing application code, but they also can switch to privileged ("kernel" or "system") mode for the duration of any system call. At this point, I don't really know anything at all about any other operating system.